# Cosa significa "spiazzato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Entrammo per accedere al «giardino»: uno **spiazzato** recinto da pareti di verde e limitato sul fondo da una balaustra di mattoni, sotto la quale scorreva l’Ema.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "spiazzato" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "spiazzare" in alcuni dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Senza leggere la risposta, propendo verso un toscanismo per “spiazzo”. I toscani adoperano spesso parole che suonano strane nel resto d'Italia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spiazzato è un sinonimo non molto comune di spiazzo.

> [spiazzata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiazzata/) s. f. [der. di piazza, col pref. s- (nel sign. 5)], non com.
>   – Spiazzo, radura. In senso fig., zona del cuoio capelluto senza più
>   capelli.

Sempre da Treccani per [spiazzo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiazzo_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)):

> spiazzo /'spjats:o/ s. m. [der. di piazza, col pref. s- (nel sign.
>   5)]. - [spazio di terreno libero in piano: *uno s. erboso*] ≈ slargo,
>   spianata, spianato, (ant.) spiano, (non com.) spiazzata, [all'interno
>   di un bosco e sim.] radura.

Nel caso da te citato è un’area piana delimitata da pareti che costituisce il giardino.